# Unity is asking for a } but I don't see why

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, syntax-error

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int speed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        public float translation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;

        translation *= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        transform.Translate(translation, 0, 0);

    }
}
```

Line 12 is giving an error for a missing closing curly bracket however I can't figure out why. I've tried google and friends however I still couldn't find a soloution to the issue and it's really annoying me.

Comment: You are calculating that "translation" and then forget about it?

Comment: Because you tried to declare public variables in Start

Answer (score 3):

It's confused by the `public` in

```
public float translation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
```

which shouldn't be there.
Change it to

```
float translation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
```

instead.

EDIT: based on the comments it seems you're simply looking for

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int speed;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float translation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
        translation *= Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(translation, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

instead. There is no point in looking at `translation` in the Start method.

Comment: Except then it cant be used in update

Comment: If you want a (public or private or whatnot) instance variable, you don't put it inside a function.

Comment: See my edit, please...

Answer (score -1):

Move variable outside the function.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int speed;
    public float translation;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        translation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
        translation *= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(translation, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: That will help with the acute issue, but doesn't do much – there will be no deltaTime elapsed during Start, nor will the horizontal axis have a value.

Comment: Exactly, this answers Op's question, nothing more.